# How to change description of a pending (shelved) changelist using command?

Tags: perforce

I've created CL#100 with some description and shelved some files.
Now I need to edit the description of that CL using a command.
I have tried these 2 ways and both failed (same error msg)

1. p4 change -u 100 "Description: test description edit"
2. p4 change -o 100 > myDes.txt >> Edit Description field in myDes.txt >> p4 change -u 100 < myDes.txt

Error:
Execution Failed: "'C:
Program" "C:\Users\iman\AppData\Local\Temp\t26660t63.tmp": The system cannot find the file specified.
Client side operation(s) failed. Command aborted.
Edited File C:\Users\iman\AppData\Local\Temp\t26660t63.tmp kept due to errors.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `P4EDITOR` is set to "C:\Program", which is making `p4` unable to launch an editor.  This will cause problems for *any* command which edits a spec, not just `p4 change` commands!  Do:

```
p4 set P4EDITOR=notepad
```

to set your editor to `notepad` (the default on Windows).

Then you should be able to run:

```
p4 change 100
```

The `-u` flag isn't needed for the update since this is a pending changelist (you can freely edit your pending changelists by default).  The description is not specified on the command line; it's part of the spec that you'll edit in the editor.

If for some reason you need to do this without an editor (e.g. you're writing a script), you need to use `-o` to output to stdout and `-i` to input from stdin.  I recommend using `--field` to modify the field instead of writing your own script to parse the changelist spec:

```
p4 --field "Description=test description edit" change -o 100 | p4 change -i
```